# Using Linked Lists in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm learning programming in C language and I face some troubles, especially when working with pointers. It's a little bit difficult for me since we don't use pointers in Java or C#.

What I try to do is to create a linked list (code found on the internet) and to push elements in it. Like in the code below.

What happens is that when I uncomment the second line of code, the code works but I receive the following list as answer {0, 1, 2}, even if I don't push the number 0 in the list. I would like to have this as answer: {1, 2}.

```
int main (){
    node_t * test_list = NULL;

    //test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    push(test_list, 1);
    push(test_list, 2);

    print_list(test_list);

    return 0;
}
```

This is how the code looks like:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int val;
  struct node * next;
}              node_t;

void print_list(node_t * head)
{
  node_t * current = head;

  while (current != NULL)
    {
      printf("%d\n", current->val);
      current = current->next;
    }
}

node_t* new_node(node_t * head)
{
  node_t * head2 = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

  return  head2;
}

void push(node_t * head, int val)
{
  if (head == NULL)
    {
      head = new_node(head);
      head->val = val;
      head->next = NULL;
    }
  else
    {
      node_t * current = head;
      while (current->next != NULL)
          current = current->next;

      /* now we can add a new variable */
      current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
      current->next->val = val;
      current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

In the push function, I decided to check whether the head is equal to NULL or not. If it's the case, I just want to create a new node and assign it to it. I don't know if it's a good approach. Nevertheless, it is not working.

I would be thankful if someone could guide me to the right path!

Thank you!

(Source of the code: http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists )

---

Comment: Did you step through the code, line-by-line in the debugger?  You are also trying to assign a pointer in push() for head, which is not going to work.  Everything in C is pass-by-value.

Comment: ^^ the right path is towards gdb, or some other debugger.

Comment: The modified `head` in `push` is not finding its way back to the caller, because you pass it a *copy* .

Comment: No I did not step through the code with the debugger. But if I uncomment the following line `//test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));` from the main function, it adds an extra element to the list (the element 0), which I don't want. That's the reason why I tried to make it work with the function `new_node(...)`, but it is not working.

Comment: suggest consistency in code formatting, so us humans can easily read/understand it.   1) always indent after every opening brace '{'  2) always un-indent before every closing brace '}'  3) never use tabs for indenting as every editor/wordprocessor has different tab widths/tab stops.  4) insert a blank line around each code block  5) add comments so the person reading the code knows what the author thinks they are doing

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc and family of functions to assure the operation was successful.   Before exiting main(), always pass all the allocated memory areas to free(), to avoid any memory leaks

Comment: in general, 1) it is best to NOT typedef structs, unions, enums.  2) in later versions of the C standard, there is the indication (not enforced,yet) that trailing '_t' in type names is reserved for the use of the language elements so should not be incorporated into user created type names

Comment: @user3629249, who did tell you that one shouldn't use `typedef`? In the contrary, I prefer something like `typedef struct node node;` before the definition of the `struct` itself. This reserves `node` in both name spaces. And the restriction for the suffix-`_t` is not part of C itself, but comes from POSIX, where it is reserved.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give an explanation of the extra element 0.

```
test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t)); //this changes the pointer test_list                
                                    //which is initially NULL to a non-NULL pointer, hence the mysterious extra element "0"

 push(test_list, 1);

void push(node_t * head, int val) {
if (head == NULL) //head is not NULL at this point because you called malloc earlier on it, so 1 will be inserted in the next position
{...}
```

You should initialize the head of the list with some value, after malloc:

```
test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));


head->val = 5; //some value
head->next = NULL;

push(test_list, 1);
...
```

Now, the first element won't be 0, it will be 5.

Comment: If I uncomment the line `//test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));` in my main function, even if I don't push elements in the linked list, the mysterious element '0' will appear.

Comment: Exactly, because malloc assigns a value to your NULL pointer and initializes it to 0, even though that's not guaranteed (use calloc for 0-initializing).

Comment: Also, if you look carefully at the source of your code, you'll see, that after malloc, the structure is initialized with some values:                  `node_t * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->val = 1;
head->next = NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

When you have uncommented the below line in your code

```
//test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Here you are allocating the head pointer before calling your push functions.
So, the below lines of code will never get executed

```
 if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node(head);
        head->val = val;
        head->next = NULL;}
```

Since you have malloced once for head pointer and you have not initialized it and followed by two push functions. So you will see 0/garbage,1,2 instead of 1,2 in your list.

And when you have commented the malloc for test_list, then in the below piece of code

```
if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node(head);
        head->val = val;
        head->next = NULL;
    }else
    {

        node_t * current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
```

Since you are not sending the address of test_list(&test_list-you need to use double pointer)any changes done to head in `if case` will not be reflected in test_list.

Go through the link for clear understanding-
[linked_list](http://geeksquiz.com/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following functions.

```
node_t * new_node( int val )
{
    node_t * n = malloc( sizeof( node_t ) );

    if ( n )
    {
        n->val = val;
        n->next = NULL;
    }

    return  n;
}

void push( node_t **head, int val ) 
{
    node_t *n = new_node( val );

    if ( n )
    {
        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;
        *head = n;
    }
}
```

Function push must be called like

```
push( &test_list, 1 );
```

As for your function `push` implementation then it deals with a copy of `test_list`. So the original value of `test_list` is not changed.

Comment: Given what his code currently looks like, I'm pretty sure your suggestion is not going to be useful to him without a bit more of a complete solution (i.e., a full usage example) (which is not a reflection on you/your answer, but rather on the broad nature of this question).

Comment: @mah What I showed is enough thet to resolve the problem with padding new elements to the list. So I do not understand the sense of your comment.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Your code is working perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Already Vlad from Moscow and Violeta Marin posted the reason why it not works.I made some changes **In your code** to make it work,

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  typedef struct node
  {
     int val;
     struct node * next;
  } node_t;

  void print_list(node_t * head) 
  {
      node_t * current = head;
      printf("called\n");
      while (current != NULL) {
         printf("%d\n", current->val);
         current = current->next;
      }
  }


  node_t* new_node()
  {
     //you have to return NULL , if malloc fails to allocate memory 
     node_t * head2 = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
     return  head2;
  }

  void push(node_t **head, int val)
  {
      if (*head == NULL)
      {
          printf("null\n");  
         //you have to check the return value of new_node
         (*head) = new_node();
         (*head)->val = val;
         (*head)->next = NULL;
      }
      else {
          printf("not null\n");
          node_t * current = *head;

          while (current->next != NULL) {
              current = current->next;
          }
          /* now we can add a new variable */
          //you have to check the return value of malloc
          current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
          current->next->val = val;
          current->next->next = NULL;
       }
  }

  void my_free(node_t *head)
  {
    node_t *temp= NULL;
    while(head) 
    {
       temp=head->next;
       free(head);
       head=temp;
    }
}
int main ()
{
   node_t *test_list = NULL;
   push(&test_list, 1);
   push(&test_list, 2);
   print_list(test_list);
   my_free(test_list);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

```
1) corrects several oversights in the posted code
2) works correctly
3) contains the logic that (generally) is always used to 
   add a node to the end of a linked list
4) demonstrates that to change the contents of a passed in pointer
   the simplest way is to pass '**' 
   and the caller passes the address of the pointer, not the contents of the pointer
5) uses consistent formatting
6) avoids unnecessary/misleading clutter/confusion in the definition of the struct
7) removes unnecessary parameters from functions
8) properly prototypes the functions 
   notice that the new_node() function prototype has '(void)'
   while the actual function body just has '()'

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
};

// prototypes
void          print_list( struct node * head);
struct node * new_node( void );
void          push( struct node ** head, int val);


int main ( void )
{

    struct node * test_list = NULL;

    push(&test_list, 1);
    push(&test_list, 2);

    print_list(test_list);

    return 0;
} // end function: main


// step through linked list, printing the val field from each node
void print_list( struct node * head)
{
    struct node * current = head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
} // end function: print_list


// create a new node
struct node * new_node()
{
    struct node * head2 = NULL;

    if( NULL == (head2 = malloc(sizeof( struct node))))
    { // then malloc failed
        // handle error, cleanup, and exit
    }

    return  head2;
} // end function: new_node


// append a new node to end of linked list
// need to use '**' so actual pointer in main() will be updated
void push( struct node ** head, int val)
{
    struct node * current = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
    { // then list is empty
        current = new_node();
        current->val = val;
        current->next = NULL;
        *head = current;
    }

    else
    {
        current = *head;

        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        /* now we can append a new node to linked list */
        current->next = new_node();
        current->next->val = val;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
} // end function: push
```